# My CS50 blur function isn't working correctly

Tags: c, blur, cs50

I'm currently working on the filter program on CS50. While it has been easy enough so far, I'm struggling with a few errors on my blur program. I feel like the issue lies in the edge cases of the program but I can't be sure. If someone could provide a hint I'd be very grateful.

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];

    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            copy[h][w] = image[h][w];
        }
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            float redaddup = 0;
            float greenaddup = 0;
            float blueaddup = 0;
            for (int r = -1; r < 2; r++)
            {
                for (int s = -1; s < 2; s++)
                {
                    if((y + r > height || y + r < 0) || (x + s > width || x + s < 0))
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        redaddup += copy[y+r][x+s].rgbtRed;
                        greenaddup += copy[y+r][x+s].rgbtGreen;
                        blueaddup += copy[y+r][x+s].rgbtBlue;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            image[y][x].rgbtRed = round(redaddup / count);
            image[y][x].rgbtGreen = round(greenaddup / count);
            image[y][x].rgbtBlue = round(blueaddup / count);

            image[y][x].rgbtRed = image[y][x].rgbtRed % 256;
            image[y][x].rgbtBlue = image[y][x].rgbtBlue % 256;
            image[y][x].rgbtGreen = image[y][x].rgbtGreen % 256;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

The errors I'm receiving are:

```
:( blur correctly filters 3x3 image
expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 85 95\n80 9..."
:( blur correctly filters 4x4 image
expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 85 95\n80 9..."
```

Additionally, i'm fairly new to programming so if anyone fancies critiquing my code feel free to. I could use the feedback.

Comment: You should check `>= height` and `>= width` as `==` is already out of range.

Comment: What is the purpose of `%256`? If you take the average of multiple valid values you cannot get a result that is too large.

Comment: It was just to check that if any of the values are over 255. I see now that this is pointless haha

Comment: In your first comment, what are you referring to? My if statement or my loop?

Comment: The if statement: `y + r > height` => `y + r >= height`

Comment: I would suggest to invert the whole if statement. Having an empty if-branch and only do something in the else branch, looks weird. => `if ((y + r < height) && (y + r >=  0) && (x + s < width) && (x + s >= 0)) { do it here! }`

Comment: Sounds like a good idea! I'll give it a try and report back

Comment: Be aware that the suggested new condition already fixes the off-by-1 error mentioned in first comment.

Comment: It worked, thanks mate. I hope Santa puts you on the good boy list this year.